# React Native "undefined is not an Object"

Tags: react-native

Code:

```
import { ImageBackground,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
    return (
        <ImageBackground
        style={styles.background} 
        source={require("../assets/background.jpg")}
        ></ImageBackground>
    );  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background:{
        flex: 1
    }
});
export default WelcomeScreen;
```

Output:

[image: Error message from android phone]

Comment: have you import react to current file ? add this on top your file `import * as React from 'react'`

Comment: that worked by adding that line i am confused now but thanks

Comment: You're welcome, if your writing jsx you should add that

Answer (score 0):

To explain why:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

fixed your problem...

You are not using just plain JavaScript in this file.
Anything that looks like a HTML tag e.g. `<ImageBackground>` is JSX and needs to be transpiled to plain JavaScript by babel (or some other transpiler).

Your transpiler needs use the React library for JSX and therefore any files using JSX require this import.